# Как проверить, установлен ли React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Как проверить, установлен ли  React js ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в проекте используется npm, то можно посмотреть в файле package.json в поле dependencies. Если есть нужный пакет в этом списке, то, соответственно, установлен. Можно вручную ещё поискать в папке node_modules. Если есть соответствующая папка, всё так же значит что установлен.